# pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: (will have no effect)

Tags: eclipse, pydev, liclipse

I am using Eclipse with pydev installed.

Debugging through pydevd.

When running the python script in the server, pydevd configured value `PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON` is being used. But If I update the `PATHS_FROM_ECLIPSE_TO_PYTHON` value second time, the first value only is being used but updated vlaue is not working.

Please help on how to make it updated

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check the `“modified date”` of `pydevd_file_utils.pyc`, because the `pydev` priority to use `pydevd_file_utils.pyc`(not `pydevd_file_utils.py`).
When you modify the `pydev_file_utils.py`, make sure the `pydev_file_utils.pyc` to be rebuilded in the same time.